Kid shoots his father and escapes, neighbour father tries to save him
I watched a movie 4-8 years ago and keep talking about it but don't remenber it's name - that's why I'm asking here for help.
General Movie Info
not older than 2000, playing in the States, thriller/drama, visual: color, I remember the movie having a blueish atmosphere.
Plot - what I remeber
There are two families living in some (bad) neighborhood. They both have a son. One family has hispanic backgrounds, the other american. The father of the hispanic family is an alcoholic and often beats his wife. One day the kid doesn't stand his fathers treatment of his mother anymore and he gets his fathers gun (as much as I know a revolver) and shoots him. Shocked of his own behaviour the kid then escapes from home. Meanwhile the father of the neighbour family heard the shot and visits the house where he finds the father shot and the mother shocked. He then tries to find the escaped kid.
The kid itself then makes his tour in the night alone where it makes its bads contacts in different places. These are a perverted pair who kidnap him and bring him into their home where they want to abuse him and other kids. The kid achieves to free himself. Later he gets to know a prostitute and so on - thats where my rememberings start to vanish. But at the end the father of the other family finds the kid.
Main actors

The Kid: 8-12 years old, short hair, not really hispanic for his parents being so
The father of the other family: 30-40 years, short hair 3-days beard

Additional tips

The movie mainly plays in one night, in the evening the kid shoots his father and in the early morning the other father finds him.
the perverted pair uses a viderecorder to record their behaviour
I think the movie ends where the father arrives in car with the kid at home and the camera does a fly-away from the scene

So that's what I can recall from the movie. Would be awesome if somebody knows it's title! Thanks in advance for any help!

Running Scared (2006)

Joey Gazelle is a low level mob flanker who gets told to dispose of a gun used for killing some dirty cops. Joey however, hides the gun in the drywall of his basement instead of tossing them in the river. When Joey's 10 year-old son and his best friend, Oleg, witness Joey hiding some guns from a botched drug deal, Oleg steals the gun -- a snub-nosed .38 -- and shoots his abusive stepfather with it. Things would be bad enough if the stepfather didn't happen to be the nephew of a psychotic Russian mob boss... who happens to be in business with Joey's crew on a gasoline scam. But now Joey's also got the surviving dirty cop from the botched drug deal on his case... and that hot .38 out there on the street, changing hands in an underworld of freaks, pimps, hookers and pedophiles. As well as Oleg, who can connect Joey to the gun. 


Awesome! That's exactly the one I was looking for - and so fast answered. Thanks a lot!
